# Why don’t compounds with high boiling points not necessarily have high attraction constants (a) in the Van der Waals equation?

Tags: gas-laws, intermolecular-forces, boiling-point

You can find a list of constants $a$ and $b$ for [the van der Waals equation in a Wikipedia website](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_(data_page)). Accordingly, hexane has a higher attraction constant ($a$) than that for water (24.71 vs 5.536), but water has a higher boiling point than hexane. So, intuitively water would have stronger attraction between gas molecules. In general, the alkanes demonstrate high $a$ values. Why is this?

My guess is that since the alkanes are symmetrical, it does not matter how the molecules near the edge of a container are oriented, they will be attracted toward the middle of the container no matter what. On the other hand, water’s asymmetry means water molecules have to be oriented a certain way in relation to the other molecules in order to be attracted to them. While in liquid form, water is more often oriented in this attractive way, but in gas form water’s orientation is more random and therefore there is less attraction while water is in gas form.

Comment: Note that a hexane molecule is quite a bit larger than a water molecule. Why is this information significant?

Comment: Any effects due to size I would expect to come into play for boiling point too

Comment: vdW parameter a is not just a measure of attractive forces, but 8s a measure of overall "being busy with other molecules, Much bigger and planar hexane molecule is much more busy.It Is a kind of a dynamic aspect of molecule size and shape.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this “busy-ness” and how it contributes to a lower measured pressure when the compressibility factor (Z) is below 1?

Comment: Comparing vdW parameters of very different molecules is imo an excercise in futility. It is a qualitatively rather bad model, and the tabulated values are calculated from the critical parameters, i.e. they belong to *different temperatures*.

Comment: I took all the data on the Wikipedia datapage and [normalised the constant **a** by the molecular weight of the compounds](https://justpaste.it/4cv0c) as a very rough measure of molecular "size". While compounds with inherently stronger intermolecular forces tend to have higher values of **a**, the agreement is only qualitative, and there are considerable sections of outliers (for example, water has the second highest MW-normalised value of **a**, but hexane is the fifth highest). There is surely a more accurate form of normalising the data, but there could also be something missing.

Comment: Closely related to "How are the Van der Waals constants a and b related to each other?" https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/125331/35806

Comment: @Ryan By "busyness" I mean general interaction,decreasing frequency of wall hitting. It means either dynamic creation of real dimers, either creation a kind of "mechanical dimers" due being obstacles for each other. E.g 2 n-haxane molecules are like 2 fisherman nets catching each other.